# How to use TikZ-libraries in TikZJax?

Tags: tikz, tikzjax

**(1a)** TikZJax-Website: https://tikzjax.com/  
**(1b)** Github: https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax   
**(2)** Demo: https://tikzjax-demo.glitch.me/

How can I use TikZ-libraries in *TikZJax*?

For example `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` and then

```
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, draw] at (2,0) {my polygon};
```

(or whatever).

I tried to put in "library-stuff" at the demo-page **(2)**, without success.

Comment: see https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax/issues/2

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ahhh haa, I understand.

Comment: x-site duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695608/36296

Answer (score 1):

Original TikZJax can't do this. [drgrice1's fork](https://github.com/drgrice1/tikzjax/tree/ww-modifications) may do this, but I'd still recommend trying [benrbray's fork](https://github.com/benrbray/tikzjax), which solved the build issues and provides a Dockerfile for a useful build guide.

So maybe you can try to put your code like this:

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, draw] at (2,0) {my polygon};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

into my live demo: https://bill-ion.github.io/tikzjax-live/ , which is mainly based on [benrbray's fork](https://github.com/benrbray/tikzjax) that allow you to use tikz-libraries (`\usetikzlibrary{*}`) and some packages (`\usepackage{*}`).